# Javascript syntax error that can't solve

Tags: javascript

There seems to be a syntax error that I can't seem to solve in JavaScript.

```
        var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><div align="center"><input type="checkbox"class="case" onclick="showhide('display','')"/></div></td><td>' + daterecorded + '</td><td>' + arrivaltime + '</td><td>' + departuretime + '</td><td>9h 30min</td><td>' + specialreason + '</td></tr>');
    jQuery('table.manual').append(newRow);
});
```

This part: onclick="showhide('display','')" has been giving me syntax errors.

I have tried this onclick="showhide(' + display + ' ' + ,''+ ')"

and get myself confused. couldn't seem to get the syntax right. any help please?

Comment: You'll never fix it if you don't even read the error message.

Comment: It's in the string you pass to jQuery. There are multiple unescaped `'` characters. Look at how `display` is highlighted in your snippet.

Comment: There is a missing blank between type="checkbox" and class. You also need to use escaped quotes, \"display\" instead of 'display'.

Comment: `align="center"` is too old. Instead of that use `text-align: center` or `margin: 0 auto` of CSS.

Comment: Just don't use inline event handler attributes, and you can save yourself triple quote-nesting. Hey, you've got jQuery around!

Answer (score 5):

```
var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><div align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" onclick="showhide(\'display\',\'\')"/></div></td><td>' + daterecorded + '</td><td>' + arrivaltime + '</td><td>' + departuretime + '</td><td>9h 30min</td><td>' + specialreason + '</td></tr>');
        jQuery('table.manual').append(newRow);
    });
```

You just need to escape the two ' around display.

Comment: And also, the other 2:
`onclick="showhide(\'display\',\'\')"`

Answer (score 0):

or you can bind event after creating row

```
        var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><div align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" /></div></td><td>' + daterecorded + '</td><td>' + arrivaltime + '</td><td>' + departuretime + '</td><td>9h 30min</td><td>' + specialreason + '</td></tr>');
    jQuery('table.manual').append(newRow);

    newRow.find(".case").click(function () { showHide('display', ''); });

});
```

dont have to mind escaping and much better to read.